# f.country_select options default country

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html-select, country

In my rails app I want the f.country_select to be `user's country`, if the user has provided the country. Else I want it to have the `Select one value`.

```
<%= f.country_select :country, nil, {:selected => @user.country, :include_blank => 'Select one'}, {:class=>'form-control'} %>
```

Anything wrong with the above code?

**Update:**

Am using the `gem 'country_select'`.

Comment: What's `@user.country` ? Can you use `@user.country || "Select one value"` ?

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this:

```
<%= f.select(:country, options_for_select(Country, :selected => @user.country), :prompt => 'Select one' , {:class=>'form-control'}) %>
```

Comment: Have updated the question. Am using `gem 'country_select'`.